# Wandb connects to company automatically

Tags: python, linux, wandb

On my laptop, wandb is configured to log in to my company's wandb. However, I want to use my personal wandb account for my personal projects. Even after `wandb login --relogin`, it will still try to go to `company.wandb.ai` instead of `api.wandb.ai`. How can I solve this?

Even better, is there a good way to handle two wandb accounts?
I cannot give details about how I set my company wandb.

Answer (score 0):

If your company is on a onprem instance (as I am assuming is the case since you mention `company.wandb.ai`), you would want to log in with `wandb login --cloud` to redirect to `api.wandb.ai`.

We store the base URL of your last login in `~/.config/wandb/settings` so you would have to mention that you are trying to log in into our cloud instance.

When trying to relogin back to your company's instance, you can use `wandb login --host=https://company.wandb.ai` (or http if https is not enabled).

The API key for each instance is stored separately in `~/.netrc`, so you should not need to use the `--relogin` flag to set up an API key each time.

Comment: Can you share the content of `~/.config/wandb/settings`? In lieu of that I have to always set env var [as this guide explains](https://docs.wandb.ai/guides/hosting/how-to-guides/basic-setup)